# Python seaborn histplot returns StopIteration

Tags: python, seaborn, stopiteration

I installed seaborn, but when I do the example from the Seaborn website, I get StopIteration message, how do I fix it?

import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm")

StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [33], line 1
----> 1 sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm")

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaZKo.jpg)

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bug in `matplotlib` that is (uniquely?) affecting `seaborn`.  See the issue ellhe-blaster linked to below.  The recommendation is to downgrade to `matplotlib` 3.6.0, e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=3.6.0`. This has resolved the issue for me (for now) and I hope it works for you, too.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seem to be in the default color definition function. If you specify a color you can skip the error:

```
sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", color='blue')
```

That solved the problem for me, hope it does for you as well.
Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with **matplotlib==3.6.1**

You have 2 variants:

1. Upgrade matplotlib up to 3.6.2 version via

```
pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

2. Downgrade matplotlib to 3.6.0 version via

```
pip install matplotlib==3.6.0 --force-reinstall
```

Both variants worked for me.
Here is the same issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3072